# Find the distance $r$ between two protons at which the electrostatic repulsion between them will equal the gravitational attraction of the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

I am a bit stuck on this problem.

I know that if they equal each other you can do,
$(Gm_1m_2)/r^2 = (kq_1q_2)/r^2$

But however no matter what I think of, I can't seem to isolate the r so I can find its corresponding value.

It always just cancels off since it appears on both sides.
I don't know if I am making like a fundamental mistake or something.

Somebody please have a look.

Comment: Since the protons position relative to Earth surface is not given,- this problem is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 different r's.  "r" for electrical force is the distance between the protons. "R" for gravity is the distance between a proton and the center of the Earth. So they do not cancel.

Comment: I may add that when  $r_{1} = r_{2}$, $$GMm= kQq$$ is the only condition for the forces to be equal, $r_{1,2}$can take any value. Hence why isolating r when the r's are equal is invalid as it can be anything